# How to join Three tables into one by EMP_ID in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to Join **3 tables** into one to collect all information about employee with **emp_id**. Problem is one **emp_id** may not be exist in another one. All emp_id s should be together and values should be written if in tables exist otherwise 0 should be written

**exchange_records**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
id       |   emp_id    | sum_exchange    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
1        |   203100    | 2291520000      |
2        |   161938    | 197809000       |
3        |   230316    | 9583832300      |
4        |   193386    | 1793223000      |
```

**swift_records**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
id       |   emp_id    | sum_swift       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
1        |   203100    | 39596400        |
2        |   171831    | 10136600        |
3        |   310531    | 707708.51       |
4        |   193386    | 38117100        |
5        |   183003    | 105363.05       |
```

**spot_records**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
id       |   emp_id    | sum_spot        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
1        |   233076    | 39596400        |
2        |   171831    | 10136600        |
3        |   200172    | 707708.51       |
4        |   163389    | 38117100        |
```

**Result should be like below**

```
-----------------------------------------
id       |  emp_id     | sum_exchange    |   sum_swift    |    sum_spot    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |  203100     | 2291520000      |   39596400     |      0         |
1        |  161938     | 197809000       |   0            |      0         |
1        |  230316     | 9583832300      |   0            |      0         |
1        |  193386     | 1793223000      |   38117100     |      0         |
1        |  171831     | 0               |   10136600     |      10136600  |
1        |  310531     | 0               |   707708.51    |      0         |
1        |  183003     | 2291520000      |   105363.05    |      0         |
1        |  203100     | 2291520000      |   0            |      0         |
1        |  233076     | 0               |   0            |      39596400  |
1        |  200172     | 0               |   0            |      707708.51 |
1        |  163389     | 0               |   0            |      38117100  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a `full join`:

```
select
    emp_id,
    coalesce(e.sum_exchange, 0) sum_exchange,
    coalesce(w.sum_swift, 0) sum_swift,
    coalesce(s.sum_spot, 0) sum_spot
from 
    exchange_records e
    full join swift_records w using(emp_id)
    full join spot_records s using(emp_id)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c4a5166cc239ba392a2d2ad1fcd767bd)**:

```
emp_id | sum_exchange |   sum_swift |    sum_spot
-----: | -----------: | ----------: | ----------:
161938 |    197809000 |           0 |           0
163389 |            0 |           0 | 38117100.00
171831 |            0 | 10136600.00 | 10136600.00
183003 |            0 |   105363.05 |           0
193386 |   1793223000 | 38117100.00 |           0
200172 |            0 |           0 |   707708.51
203100 |   2291520000 | 39596400.00 |           0
230316 |   9583832300 |           0 |           0
233076 |            0 |           0 | 39596400.00
310531 |            0 |   707708.51 |           0
```

Comment: I did not know that full join has this kind of feature